# How to parse timezone with datetime to a datetime parameter

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I am using saber soap API for flight Booking.

I have an `DateTime` object which requires a parameter with the timezone. The input should be like `"2016-03-01T10:00:00-06:00"`

At the moment I am getting the value like

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
string date = dt.ToString();
string tstamp = dt.ToString("mm-dd-yyyyTHH:mm:sszzz");
DateTimeOffset tstamp = DateTimeOffset.Parse(date);
DateTime datetime = tstamp.DateTime;
```

but when I convert it back to `DateTime` the timezone gets removed automatically. I cannot convert the object to `DateTimeoffset` because the API requires it in the `DateTime` format.

Comment: for the api use the datetime itself .And when you need the offset use the DatetimeOffset .Am i missing anything?

Comment: nope you are right

Answer (score 2):

I think this could help you, it is possible to get the dateTime you desire or to get the offset as TimeSpan and then add it to your datetime if needed or save it.

*Edit:*
now I see you maybe just need to get the string from a DateTimeOffset object, not from a DateTime object.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
string date = dt.ToString();
string tstampString = dt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyyTHH:mm:ssZZZ");

DateTimeOffset tstampDT = DateTimeOffset.Parse(date);

DateTime datetimeCurrent = tstampDT.DateTime;
DateTime datetimeUTC = tstampDT.UtcDateTime;
DateTime datetimeLocal = tstampDT.LocalDateTime;
TimeSpan offsetFromUTC = tstampDT.Offset;
```

edit:

```
string tstampOffsetString = tstampDT.ToString("MM-dd-yyyyTHH:mm:sszzz");
```

Comment: A few things; There is not `ZZZ` as a custom format specifier. Those custom specifiers are case sensitive. Even if you mention `zzz` specifier, it is not recomended to use it with `DateTime` since it reflects system timezone offset for a DateTime. It is not related with `Kind` property at all. Creating your `DateTimeOffset` based on your `DateTime` is nor enough because you should specify UTC Offset part if you wanna generate `-06:00` as a result with `zzz` specifier.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I put ZZZ because I was warned not to use 'z' with a DateTimeInvelidLocalFormat, off course in my code: tstampString = "06-23-2016T12:12:57ZZZ" and tstampOffsetString = "06-23-2016T12:12:57+02:00"

Answer (score 0):

I try to explain a few things;

> I have an DateTime object which requires a parameter with the
>   timezone.

No, you *don't*.

A `DateTime` does not have *any* implicit format. It just have date and time values. "Format" concept *only* applies when you get it's *textual* (aka `string`) representation. So you may have a string that has offset part but not DateTime.

> but when I convert it back to DateTime the timezone gets removed
>   automatically..

And a `DateTime` itself does not contain a *real* timezone information. It *may* know if it's `UTC` or `Local`, but **not** what local *really* means. Also `DateTimeOffset` does not have timezone information either. It just have a `DateTime` and [UTC Offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). But those informations are not enough to determine a timezone since different timezones *may* have the same offset.

But if you *really* wanna generate `"2016-03-01T10:00:00-06:00"` input, I can provide 2 ways *even* I don't suggest;

Genereate related `DateTime` instance based on that value, set your system timezone which has `6` hours behind as an offfset part (since using [`zzz` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#zzzSpecifier) is not recommended for DateTime which does not relate `Kind` property) and format your `DateTime` like;

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2016, 3, 1, 10, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"));
// 2016-03-01T10:00:00-06:00
```

Generate `DateTimeOffset` instance based on that DateTime and offset part, after you format it like;

```
var dto = new DateTimeOffset(dt, TimeSpan.FromHours(-6));
Console.WriteLine(dto.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"));
// 2016-03-01T10:00:00-06:00
```